# Midpoint Rule Simpsons Rule Trap Rule Error Bounds

Tags: calculus, numerical-calculus

[image]

I need help on the error part. I know the formula for finding the error but I am having trouble determining what $k$ should be. Is $k$ just any number?

Answer (score 2):

Let's do the analysis for TRAP. The formula that you wrote that you know probably reads something like
$$\frac{(b-a)^3}{12n^2}|f''(\xi)|,$$
where $\xi$ is a number between $a$ and $b$.

In our case, $b=2$, and $a=0$. Also, our function $f(x)$ is $\cos(x^3)$. Then $f'(x)=- 3x^2\sin(x^3)$ and therefore $f''(x)=-9x^4\cos(x^3)-6x\sin(x^3)$. We want to find an upper bound $B$ on $|f''(x)|$ in our interval. It is not clear how hard we should work to get a **cheap** upper bound. A crude one is that since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are never bigger than $1$, we have $|f''(x)|\le 9(2^4)+12=156$.

So our error if we use $n$ intervals is $\le \frac{8}{12n^2}(156)=\frac{104}{n^2}$.

To make sure this is less than $10^{-4}$, we solve the inequality $\frac{104}{n^2}\lt 10^{-4}$, or equivalently $n^2\gt (104)(10000)$. The smallest integer that works is $n=1020$.

**Remark:** Note that our calculation does not show that $n=1020$ is **needed**, only that for sure it will do the job.

For one thing, the maximum of the second derivative over our interval is under $50$.
Far more relevant is that when we use the **maximum** for our estimate of $|f''(\xi)|)$ we are for most functions being very pessimistic. The error will usually be far smaller than the pessimistic estimate we made, and the required $n$ therefore far smaller. The estimates are not used in practical work. Roughly speaking, one doubles the number of points used until the answer becomes stable enough.

Comment: you did f"(2) to get 156?

Comment: No, I was cruder than that! We have $|\cos x|\le 1$, $|\sin x|\le 1$, and therefore for positive $x$, $9x^4\cos x+6x\sin x\le 9x^4+6x$.

Comment: can the same k be used for the midpoint error bound and simpsons?

Comment: What is the point in answering you when you don't read what we write? The Simpson's Rule $K$ is different as I clearly wrote below.

Comment: If I recall (but my memory is poor) the midpoint rule estimate has a $24$ at the bottom instead of the $12$ of TRAP. So same calculation, with small changes. For SIMP, is different. Use error estimate for SIMP, use the fact you are told that the fourth derivative is $\le 850$. In general outline it is the same sort of calculation as the one I did. At the end you will be taking a fourth root instead of a square root.

Comment: @user71317: Please note that I had a calculational error, which has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For the midpoint and trapezoidal rules $K$ is the maximum magnitude of the second derivative over the interval.

$$K=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f''(x)|.$$

For Simpsons rule is of the fourth derivative

$$K_S=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f^{iv}(x)|.$$

I am guessing that the functions have to be twice respectively four times continuously differentiable as your one is.

For part (b) they have given you an upper bound for $K$.

Comment: what do you mean by maximum magnitude?

Comment: Edited. Maximum of the magnitude/absolute value.

Comment: how do you find the max?

Comment: It might not always be possible... differentiate $\cos(x^3)$ a couple of times and see what you get. You asked for what $K$ was.

Comment: is k a number or a function?

Comment: A number. Say for the Simpson's Rule, the (absolute value of the) fourth derivative is a continuous function so attains it absolute maximum on $[0,2]$. Its maximum is $K_S$. Sometimes it is hard to find so we just say that the max is less than something. In this example $K_S$ is given to you as $850$.